# NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 Cannot open files in the “md” format

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

I'm developing a macOS application for editing files, but am getting a rather annoying error when trying to use `NSDocumentController.shared.makeDocument` to create a new `NSDocument` instance from a file URL.

Below is a simple example of how I am calling `makeDocument`. The file `test.md` exists on disk.

```swift
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/Users/me/Desktop/test.md"

do {
  let newDocument = try NSDocumentController.shared.makeDocument(withContentsOf: url, ofType: url.pathExtension)
  print("Created \(newDocument)")
} catch {
  print("Error: \(error)")
}
```

The problem is that this `try` call fails and it reaches the `catch` block. The error I get is:

> Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=256 "“test.md” could not be handled because MyApp cannot open files in the “md” format." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=“test.md” could not be handled because MyApp cannot open files in the “md” format., NSLocalizedFailureReason= MyApp cannot open files in the “md” format.}

I believe i've correctly set my app's Document Types for markdown files as shown below:

[image: info]

I've tried cleaning the build , removing derived data and also adding an 'Imported UTI' type for markdown files but nothing seems to work.

The strange thing is that via File > Open, I am able to open `.md` files, just not programatically via `makeDocument`.

Comment: `makeDocument(withContentsOf:ofType:)` calls `documentClass(forType:)`, allocates a document object and calls `init(contentsOf:ofType:)`. Which one doesn't work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`makeDocument(withContentsOf:ofType:)` expects a type as second parameter, not an extension. Have a look at `typeForContents(of url: URL)` on how to derive the type from an URL.

See Figure 6-3 in https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/DocBasedAppProgrammingGuideForOSX/AdvancedTopics/AdvancedTopics.html

And as Marek H pointed out in his answer, in the info.plist there should be an UTI (identifier) for the document type.

Comment: He also doesn't have correct UTI registered "net.daringfireball.markdown"

Comment: The UTI wasn't the problem, it was the fact that I wasn't creating the type correctly as answered above.

Answer (score 1):

Verify generated Info.plist with example from XCode 10 Info.plist and their settings.
Also check lsregister command and see if your app is registered to handle md.

lsregister (use switch dump or read man):

```
/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/LaunchServices.framework/Versions/A/Support/lsregister
```

Markdown document:

```
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleTypeName</key>
    <string>Markdown Document</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeExtensions</key>
    <array>
        <string>md</string>
        <string>mdown</string>
        <string>markdown</string>
        <string>text</string>
    </array>
    <key>LSItemContentTypes</key>
    <array>
        <string>net.daringfireball.markdown</string>
    </array>
    <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
    <string>Editor</string>
    <key>CFBundleTypeIconFile</key>
    <string>net-daringfireball-markdown</string>
</dict>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue for the millionth time just now.

I was trying to create an ObjC Mac app that opens CSS documents, but I didn't realize I was using the wrong "identifier" for the CSS document type in my Info.plist.

Here's how I discovered the root problem and fixed it.

---

I first overrode and set a breakpoint in `-[NSDocumentController documentClassForType:]` to discover what the exact `typeName` is that was failing to create an instance of my `NSDocument` subclass (`Document` in my case):

[image]

Inspect the `typeName` argument there. In my case, it was `public.css`.

Now go to edit your App Target and click on the `Info` tab.

[image]

Expand the `Document Types` item and find the document type you are having problems with (CSS in my case).

[image]

Make sure the value in the `Identifier` field matches the value you just inspected while debugging the `-documentClassForType:` method (in my case `public.css`).

These must match. I had the wrong value here (in my case, I had `org.w3.css`, which is wrong).